# Apply the same CSS animation on hovering over two different elements

Tags: html, css

I was trying to make an animation as an exercise to learn. When I hover over the circle, I want to apply an animation to it and also for the text in the `.hide` element to appear. But when I hover the circle and then move the mouse over the text, the animations stop.

Is there a way to keep both animation going even if I hover the text in the `.hide` element? I've tried to create an `:hover` subclass for the `.hide` class with animations, tried to add the animation to the `.hide` class, and tried both together, but I can't figure it out.

Also, that little black line that pops up at the beginning of the hover is annoying, if anyone know how to get rid of it.

```css
.container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.circle-icon {
  background: gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 15px;
  color: white;
  transition: padding 1s;
  margin: 0px;
}

.circle-icon:hover {
  padding: 30px;
  animation-name: spin;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 2;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

.hide {
  position: relative;
  left: -15px;
  display: none;
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0 50px 50px 0;
  margin: 0px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: white;
  animation-name: slide;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-direction: forward;
}

.circle-icon:hover + .hide {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100px;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    rotate: 0deg;
  }
  100% {
    rotate: 360deg;
  }
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    width: 0px;
    font-size: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100px;
    font-size: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7dd2bd858f.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-home circle-icon"></i>
        <span class="hide">HOME</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please note that questions here should be self-contained and include the relevant code, as external links can change or break over time and make the question unhelpful to other users. Please [edit] your question to include the code here - you can see how to [put your code in a runnable Stack Snippet here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: Welcome to SO, I hope you will get the answer soon, I am voting up, great work! I can see that little line is actually **blue**, I'm not sure why, since in CSS code we only have white and gray colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few changes you need, I've explained each one after the example, but in summary:

The main reason you are having issues is because you are acting on the hover over the `circle-icon` only - this means when you move the mouse off it (even if it is to the associated text) the hover effect ends. Therefore you need to act on hovering over the *whole* link, not just the circle.

**Working Example**:

```css
.container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.circle-icon {
  background: gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 15px;
  color: white;
  transition: padding 1s;
  margin: 0px;
}

a.icontextlink { text-decoration:none;}

.icontextlink:hover .circle-icon {
  padding: 30px;
  animation-name: spin;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 2;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

.hide {
  position: relative;
  left: -15px;
  display: none;
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0 50px 50px 0;
  margin: 0px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: white;
  animation-name: slide;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-direction: forward;
}

.icontextlink:hover .hide {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100px;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
     transform: rotate(360deg); 
  }
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    width: 0px;
    font-size: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100px;
    font-size: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7dd2bd858f.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <div class="container">
      <a href="#" class="icontextlink">
        <i class="fas fa-home circle-icon"></i>
        <span class="hide">HOME</span>
      </a>
    </div>
```

**Changes to make it work:**

**1. Add a class to the link** so we can apply CSS to it and not all `a` elements in your container, e.g.

```
<a href="#" class="icontextlink">
    <i class="fas fa-home circle-icon"></i><span class="hide">HOME</span>
</a>
```

**2. Add the animation to the circle when the whole link is hovered**. We do this by changing the CSS selector from `.circle-icon:hover` to `.icontextlink:hover .circle-icon`, e.g.:

```
.icontextlink:hover .circle-icon { animation-name: spin; /* etc... */ }
```

**3. Display the `hide` class when the whole link is hovered** - this means that even if you move the mouse off the circle and onto the text, it is still part of the same link so the effect does not end. So we change the selector from `.circle-icon:hover + .hide` to `.icontextlink:hover .hide`:

```
.icontextlink:hover .hide {  display: inline-block; /* etc... */ }
```

**4. Hide the blue line on hover** - The blue line you see is the default styling for links in the browser. We can turn this
off using `text-decoration:none;`, e.g.

```
a.icontextlink { text-decoration:none;}
```

**5. Fix the rotation animation** FYI, you don't mention it in your question but the spin animation is not working. This is because you are using e.g. `rotate: 0deg;`. The correct way is `transform: rotate(0deg);`:

```
@keyframes spin {
  0%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer. It helps me also understand why it didn't work and it's really good since I'm learning. Thank you so much!

Comment: @lpianta Glad to help! You said you were learning (and you're doing a good job BTW!), so I explained everything to help you understand the changes so you know what they do and be able to learn from it :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so:

1. For the "little black line" - it's the `text-decorator` property of the `a` tag.
2. For the animation - the problem was that when you don't `hover` on the home button (since you move the cursor or whatsoever), the `:hover` does not apply and you back to `display:none`, but then the button moves to the cursor and you again hovering it (and so on till the end of times). So I just set that when you hover on the text, the display is `inline-block`.

```css
.container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.circle-icon {
  background: gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 15px;
  color: white;
  transition: padding 1s;
  margin: 0px;
}

.hide:hover {
  display: inline-block;
}

.hide {
  position: relative;
  left: -15px;
  display: none;
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0 50px 50px 0;
  margin: 0px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: white;
  background-color: gray;
  animation-name: slide;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-direction: forward;
}

.circle-icon:hover+.hide {
  display: inline-block;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    rotate: 0deg;
  }
  100% {
    rotate: 360deg;
  }
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    width: 0px;
    font-size: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 80px;
    font-size: 100%;
  }
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7dd2bd858f.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fas fa-home circle-icon"></i>
      <span class="hide">HOME</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the black line I did:

```
*{
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

at the top of the css document

also i made the text showing up animation smoother:

```
@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    width: 0px;
    font-size: 0%;
  }

  25% {
    font-size: 0%;
  }

  27% {
    font-size: 20%;
  }

  100% {
    width: 100px;
    font-size: 100%;
  }
}
```